# SSIS Execute Process Task with lower priority

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012

I'm using SSIS from MSSQL 2012. Its Execute Process Task component is used to execute any app.

I'd like to execute an app with lower priority, so that it doesn't make all other processes hang while it is running.

In cmd.exe we can use `start /low`. Is there a way to do it in SSIS without wrapping the app execution command inside a batch file?

Answer (score 0):

Using the execute process task, you can assign the use the start /low in the arguments section. I think it would just work fine. Are you facing any issues with doing this?

Here is a [link](http://sqlserverrider.wordpress.com/2013/01/03/executing-msdos-commands-in-ssis/) that can help you.

Comment: It didn't work. If I call cmd.exe and pass the `start /low /C path\app.exe parameter1 parameter2` as parameter, either app.exe doesn't receive its parameters, or it isn't executed in low priority.

Answer (score 0):

Currently SSIS does not provide any facility to set priority for components.You can implement your own mechanism as per package requirement.

**MSDN Workaround:**

> Group your low priority tasks with equivalent dependencies into a
>   sequence container. Add a pre execute event to your higher priority
>   task that sets a bool variable indicating that the task has started.
>   Add a while loop that tells the thread to sleep of some period of time
>   (5 seconds?) while the variable is false. Make the sequence container
>   with the low priority tasks dependent on the while loop completing.
>   Some care will need to be taken to avoid deadlocking the package
>   because loops are waiting for something that never happens.
>
> While not ideal it is an improvement. If it works as expected you end
>   up with one thread that is effectively idle while it monitors to see
>   if your higher priority tasks have started. Once it checks off all of
>   the things it is monitoring the sequence container becomes active and
>   your lower priority tasks can begin executing.

Also you can use script component to query system resources.